# Kafka get timestamp based on offset and partition for monitoring time lag

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I have code in place to find offsets and TopicPartition from the `KafkaConsumer`, but can't find a way to just retrieve the timestamp based on that information.

I have looked through  `ConsumerRecord` but since this is a monitoring service I do not think I should `.poll()` as I might cause some records to fall through if my monitoring service is directly polling from Kafka.

I know there's CLI `kafka-console-consumer` which can fetch the timestamp of a message based on partition and offset, but not sure if that's an SDK available for that.

Does anyone have any insights or readings I can go through to try to get time lag?  I have been trying to find an SDK or any type of API that can do this.

Comment: "_know there's CLI `kafka-console-consumer` ... but not sure if that's an SDK available for that_" - The Console Consumer is a literal wrapper around `consumer.poll()`.

Answer (score 2):

There is no other way (as of 3.1) to do this - you can do `consumer.poll`. Of course, if you want to access only one, then you should set the max received records property to 1, so you don't waste effort. A consumer can be basically treated as an accessor to remote record-array, what you are doing is just accessing `record[offset]`, and getting this record's ts.

So to sum it up:

- get timestamp out of offset -> `seek` + `poll 1`,
- get offset out of timestamp -> `offsetsForTimes`.

Answer (score 2):

If I understood your question, given a `ConsumerRecord`, from [Kafka 0.11+, all records have a `.timestamp()`](https://kafka.apache.org/0110/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/ConsumerRecord.html#timestamp()) method.

Alternatively, given a topic, (list of) partition(s), and offset(s), then you'd need to `seek` a consumer, with `max.poll.records=1`, then extract the timestamps from each polled partition after the seeked position.

The [Confluent Monitoring Interceptors](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/control-center/installation/clients.html) already do something very similiar to what you're asking, but for Control Center.